# XCode 4.6 not showing reference language for localization

Tags: localization, xcode4.6

I have an iPad app, XCode 4.6.2, Storyboards, iOS 6.0 and ARC.  The app runs fine, now I'm trying to localize it, starting with the Storyboards using Base Localization.  This is what I see when I go to Proj Info:

[image]

When I click on Use Base Internationalization, this is what I get:

[image]

Notice that there is NO resource file or reference language to select!  Why?  and how do I fix this?  I have searched SO, Google and found nothing.

**UPDATE**  I don't want to delete this, but the answer is:  Base Localization is NOT supported under iOS... bummer!

Comment: Base Localization works with auto layout, which you may have disabled in favor of springs and struts. If this is the case you will need to localize the files singly by using the file inspector for each localizable resource. I don't understand why you are seeing the storyboard as a language however. Could you create a test project and attempt to localize the storyboard? I think this will clarify whether or not the behavior we are seeing is an anomaly or a bug in Xcode 4.6.2.